# Plotting data from two different ShapeDataFrames on the same map

Tags: r

I can plot, on separate figures, the following data from 2 different SpatialDataFrames with identical co-ord systems and polygons.
`spplot(l2cut1CV$SDF,"Intercept", col=NA)`,
and
`spplot(l3cut1CV$SDF,"Intercept", col=NA)`
How can I plot these two sets of data side by side in the same figure?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have you tried `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` ?

Comment: Use `dput` to help create reproducible code within your stackoverflow question

Comment: Thanks for the 'par' suggestion. The problem I have is that.                > par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> spplot(lcrm2AIC$SDF,"Intercept",col=NA,at = seq(0,14,2))
> spplot(lcrm2AIC2$SDF,"Intercept",col=NA,at = seq(0,14,2))                  still only gives one plot at a time not the 2 plots sidebyside I expected Paul E